# how to remove nameerror Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I am making a series using three dictionaries, in dictionary, there is no keyword or values "name"/ "null".but it is showing NameError: name 'null' is not defined

rerun the code in different jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
p1=pd.Series({'team':'england','keyplayer':'joe root','bowler':'jofra'})
p2=pd.Series({'team':'india','keyplayer':'virat kohli','bowler':'bumhra'})
p3=pd.Series({'team':'australia','keyplayer':'steve smith','bowler':'starc'})
df=pd.DataFrame([p1,p2,p3],index=['1','2','3'])

df.head()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    400                         if cls is not object \
    401                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 402                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    403 
    404             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    695     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    696     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 697     output = repr(obj)
    698     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    699         if idx:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __repr__(self)
     80         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     81         """
---> 82         return str(self)
     83 
     84 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __str__(self)
     59 
     60         if compat.PY3:
---> 61             return self.__unicode__()
     62         return self.__bytes__()
     63 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __unicode__(self)
    661             width = None
    662         self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 663                        line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
    664 
    665         return buf.getvalue()


NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

----------------after this table is showing

Comment: The code that you posted does not produce any error messages. Please include the full error message that you see.

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()


...............NameError: name 'null' is not defined...

Comment: it is also showing the table but i am not able to perform  df.loc[:,['keyplayer','bowler']]

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
..................................NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: Please, _modify_ your original question by including properly formatted full error message.

Comment: i am not able to modify the question can i ask it again

Comment: You can modify the question. There is an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56412423/edit) button.

Comment: sir i am facing same error when i am importing .csv file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code in an isolated environment and I managed!

IPython:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                              

In [2]: p1=pd.Series({'team':'england','keyplayer':'joe root','bowler':'jofra'}) 
      : p2=pd.Series({'team':'india','keyplayer':'virat kohli','bowler':'bumhra'}) 
      : p3=pd.Series({'team':'australia','keyplayer':'steve smith','bowler':'starc'}) 
      : df=pd.DataFrame([p1,p2,p3],index=['1','2','3'])                                                                                  

In [3]: df.head()                                                                                                                        
Out[3]: 
        team    keyplayer  bowler
1    england     joe root   jofra
2      india  virat kohli  bumhra
3  australia  steve smith   starc
```

I installed the minimum required to run: `numpy==1.16.4`, `pandas==0.24.2` e `jupyter==1.0.0`

Maybe there is some problem with your libs.
I recommend you try to run your code using **virtualenv** and install the required libraries.
To learn more, nothing better than the Python documentation itself: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html